Why Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile does not implement IDisposable?
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile (link) is the default implementation of IFormFile which represents a file sent with the HttpRequest. This class contains a Stream, as such it should implement IDisposable.
How come it does not? Is there a design reason behind this?

FormFile takes a Stream as a constructor parameter but it is not responsible for that stream. What if the thing calling FormFile wanted to reuse the stream?

Because FormFile is not the owner of the stream, it accepts stream (request one) as constructor parameter which is passed to it by the ASP.NET Core machinery (for example here). Request stream for example can be buffered and read multiple times or it can contain multiple files, etc. so the FormFile should not dispose it, hence it does not implement IDisposable.

Thanks, I also found a useful tip on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose (If your class has an IDisposable field or property but doesn't own it, meaning the class doesn't create the object, then the class doesn't need to implement IDisposable)

@DudePascalou yes, ownership is the main point. But note that class can own and dispose resource even if it does not create it. For example StreamReader by default assumes ownership of the resource (passed stream) but allows to override this behavior by leaveOpen ctor parameter
